# Calling PHP script with Cordova

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova

I'm working on an app that's supposed to contain the same information as an already existing website.

What I wanted to do was create a Cordova app that calls an external PHP script which in turn gets information from the database that the website is using.

Right now I'm working on calling the PHP script but it just doesn't seem to work.

Here is the script I'm trying to call:

```
<?php
 $a = 1;
 $b = json_encode($a);
 return $b;
?>
```

Ofcourse this is just to test the connection. The URL for this file is `http://localhost:8888/get_posts.php`

Here is the code for the app:

```
$('#page1').bind('pageshow', function () {
    $.get('localhost:8888/get_posts.php', function (data) {
        $(this).find('.homeText').html(data);
    });
});
```

This fetches the file whenever the page is shown (handy) and then puts the new data into the page. The problem is that the page remains empty at all times, when it should be showing a "1". Can anyone see where it goes wrong?

Error message: XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8888/get_posts.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

**UPDATE:** The error message dissapeared when adding `http://` to the url, but the problem persists.

I've changed the code to:

```
$('#page1').bind('pageshow', function () {
    $.get('localhost:8888/get_posts.php', function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

and it shows me an empty alert box.

**Solution:** Had to use `echo` instead of `return` for the script to show me a result.
`http://` was also required so the script is allowed to communicate.

Comment: check your javascript console and network for errors , please

Comment: First check where to look further: Does the ajax response show the expected value?

Comment: @delueg My bad, error included in question.

Comment: yep.. you can include this on top of your get_posts.php PHP file: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: @delueg Doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @delueg I've added http:// to the url and the error is now gone, but still no results in the page.

Comment: i edited my comment .. did you paste ---- header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); in your get_posts.php file in the first line and still getting the same error?

Comment: @delueg The error is gone because I've added http:// to the url, but the problem persists.

Comment: ahh i see the error.. $(this) in this context is your jquery.get function.. and not your #page1 element.. change it to $("#page1")

Comment: @delueg I've changed this but its still not showing any result. I've changed the code to just `alert(data);` and it shows me an empty alert.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53948/discussion-between-delueg-and-user1433479)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to 'echo' your response not returning it like so

```
<?php
 $a = 1;
 $b = json_encode($a);
 echo $b;
?>
```